# Local linear trend-exponential smoothing duality with non-Gaussian likelihood?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, state-space-models, exponential-smoothing, bsts

Say we have the following state space/structural time series model:

$$
y_t \mid \mu, \sigma \sim \text{Normal(} \mu = \mu_t, \sigma^2_\varepsilon) \\
\mu_{t+1} = \mu_t + \eta_t
$$

where

$$
\eta_t \sim \text{Normal}(0,\sigma^2_\eta)
$$

It is proven in [Muth (1960)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1960.10482064) that the model outlined above is equivalent to simple exponential smoothing, with smoothing weight given by $\frac{\sigma^2_\eta}{\sigma^2_\varepsilon}$. Muth proves this by minimizing the sum of squared errors (SSE) and re-expressing the above process as an infinite sum of previous observed values.

Now suppose we modify the model above to a non-normal likelihood, say a Gamma (using mean-dispersion parameterization here):

$$
y_t \mid \mu, \phi \sim \text{Gamma}(\mu = \exp(\mu_t), \phi) \\
\mu_{t+1} = \mu_t + \eta_t
$$

Is there any proof of the properties of the above process (or similar non-normal exponential family distribution) when we don't have a normal likelihood anymore? Does it still approximate an exponentially smoothed forecast, perhaps in log space? Is this unreasonable to expect? My gut says that this property only holds true under normal likelihood due to the proof relying on minimizing the sum of squared errors.

Comment: what you wrote initially is called the random walk + noise model which is equivalent to the ARIMA(0,1,1) which is equivalent to single exponential smoothing. Once you change the error term you've got some kind of GLM type of framework. ( yes, it's no longer equivalent ). I would look at Andrew Harvey's blue book. I don't know if he has anything about that in his book but he might. Mike West ( Duke, the last I knew ) used to work in GLMs for state space modelling. His website might be a good place to look also.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Forecasting-Structural-Time-Harvey/dp/0521405734/ref=sr_1_1?crid=8LC191BL6RY0&keywords=andrew+harvey+time+series&qid=1697245254&sprefix=andrew+harvey+time+series%2Caps%2C102&sr=8-1

Comment: I have this paper somewhere but a lot of things are in storage. There might be a way to get it without paying for JSTOR or JPASS. I don't know. It's the Mike West related paper that I was referring to.  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288042?typeAccessWorkflow=login

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mlofton, I am happy to hear my intuition was correct. Question: surely if we run this formulation on the log of y_{t} (such that the original unlogged version is lognormal) then the equivalence will hold in log space right?

Comment: not really because you will end up with a log-normal error term so translating that to arima space is not going to work because it requires iid normal error terms. My best guess is that you are in GLM space. Check out West's paper. I've never dealt with them ( GLMs in state space ) but it can't be much more complicated than the whole bayesian-dlm framework is in the first place. And it sounds like you are already pretty familiar with that.  I'm not too knowledgeable on the Gamma but is there a reason why you want to take the exponent of the mean rather than just the mean ?

Comment: Actually, since I don't know your background and am telling you to read West's paper, I should back up. If you haven't read West's "yellow book", then you should read that first because it was kind of the DLM-structural model bible when I was in grad school. Other books are around but it comes from kind of the horse's mouth in the yellow book. It's by Harrison and West and it may even contain info about transformations that I'm not recalling !!!!!  I'll link to it in the next comment. Title escapes me at the moment.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Bayesian-Forecasting-Dynamic-Springer-Statistics/dp/0387947256/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2QZ0LBBTPJ3JU&keywords=harrison+and+west+dynamic+linear+models&qid=1697252318&sprefix=harrison+and+west+dynamic+linear+models%2Caps%2C84&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.f5122f16-c3e8-4386-bf32-63e904010ad0

Comment: and apologies for noise if you're already quite familiar with text above.  I think going through that may help as far as doing some kind of transformation for normality etc.

Comment: You don't need Normal errors for the Muth result to hold, just additive errors and an additive update process for the $\mu_t$ (and zero means, finite variances, and independence, to be more complete.)  The process you suggest doesn't have an additive update process for the actual $\mu$ of the $y_t$, so the Muth result won't hold for it.

Comment: Hi jbowman. with additive errors and an additive update, they ( random walk plus noise, exponential smoothing and arima(0,1,1) will be equivalent algebraically. But in terms of the distribution of errors, arima(0,1,1) assumes that the error term for the MA part of the process is normal.  So, technically, the associated random walk plus noise model should have normal error terms also.

Comment: hi jbowman: Let me re-state my comment above. If you are only referring to the arima(0,1,1) and ES, then you are correct. All one needs is additive errors and an additive update. Clearly the error term doesn't exist in ES so what I said in response to you, only applies to the random walk plus noise model. Really the equivalence statement should be re-worded: The random walk plus noise model and ARIMA(0,1,1) are equivalent time series models and the predictions from ES are equivalent to those from an estimated ARIMA(0,1,1) and an estimated random walk + noise model.  My apologies for confusion.

Comment: @jbowman In that case, can I just add a lognormal error to the update process on $\mu_t$, initialize the process at some positive value, and drop the exponentiation on $\mu_t$ in the gamma likelihood?

Comment: @mlofton The exponentiation is necessary because the updating equation of $mu_t$ can be any real number (as it is written) - the logic is pretty well the same with a gamma GLM for example where the log-link is usually assumed. The gamma requires a positive mean parameter. Thanks for the resources - I didn't know these kinds of models actually had a name. Skimming through the resources, note that having a set of updating equations is somewhat irrelevant in my case as I'm just turning the crank with Stan anyway.

Comment: @mlofton - yes, that's my point.  Also, you have to put an "@" in front of the user ID for SE to notify someone that you'd like them to look at your comment or are replying to their comment!

Comment: Oh one more thing before I log out:  if you have a different error term on your response, then that can really mess up the updating equations for the DLM. I'm no longer familar with STAN because I used it so long ago,  so I don't know how the variances are specified but it might be better ( easier ? ) to use the DLM package in R. I can't say for sure but there's a good useR book on the DLM package in R.

Comment: @aranglol : I hadn't checked out amazon for the latest time series books in R so I decided to check it out. By coincidence, I found the book below which could be good ( I don't know ) and is definitely relevant,  given your question. I hope it helps.  https://www.amazon.com/Time-Analysis-State-Space-Model-Stan/dp/9811607133/ref=sr_1_23?crid=MZ7L480935G8&keywords=R+Time+Series+Analysis&qid=1698254123&s=books&sprefix=r+time+series+analysis%2Cstripbooks%2C74&sr=1-23&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.f5122f16-c3e8-4386-bf32-63e904010ad0#customerReviews

Comment: @mlofton It looks highly relevant! Thanks for the recommendation and all of the help, will give that book a read!

Comment: I'm glad that you think it will help.